# :not() selector not working with specificity

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply styling for every H2 element apart from those elements  in the footer.

My css simply goes as follows:

```
h2{
   text-align: center;
}
```

And if I'm to use the `:not()` selector ideally the code should be like this:

```
h2:not(#footer h2){
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to be specific about an element? For e.g. `.class.class h2` That'd be really really useful!

I'm guessing it's not allowed, but can anyone find a suitable solution? (I'd rather write my code with one line rather than loads of lines for specificity).

Thanks

Comment: `h2:not(#footer) {...}` ?

Comment: ```#footer``` is a huge container element which doesn't apply the styles.

Comment: Then 

div:not(#footer) h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: I think not only works as a simple selector - ie only one class / id / element: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `:not()` in css works. One way to do this is to set specific class for each `h2` in footer and use not like this.

```css
h2:not(.footer) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>lorem</h2>
<footer>
  <h2 class="footer">ipsum</h2>
</footer>
```